# Matching pairs of cells while iterating through columns to then return a new pair of cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a code that will take one cell and then iterate through another column to find a match, once it has found a match it will then match two other cells in that same row and return the value of a 5th and 6th cell. However, it is not working! any suggestions??

```
Sub rates()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 2187

        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 11).Value Then
            If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 12).Value Then
                Cells(i, 20) = Cells(i, 1).Value
                Cells(i, 21) = Cells(i, 11).Value
                Cells(i, 22) = Cells(i, 4).Value
                Cells(i, 23) = Cells(i, 16).Value
            Else
                Cells(i, 24) = "No match"
            End If
        End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fully qualifying your cell objects i.e. `sheet1.cells(i,1).value` etc or encase within a `with` statement i.e.

```
with sheet1
   if .cells(i,X) = .cells(i,Y) then
   '...etc
end with
```

I think the default property for a range is "Value" but try putting .Value on to the end of all those Cell lines too... like you have for half of them :)

[EDIT/Addition:]

... failing that, you're not actually searching a whole column at any point: try something like:

```
Sub rates()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rgSearch As Range
    Dim rgMatch As Range
    Dim stAddress As String
    Dim blMatch As Boolean

    With wsSheet
        Set rgSearch = .Range(.Cells(x1, y1), .Cells(x2, y2)) ' Replace where appropriate (y = 1 or 11 i guess, x = start and end row)
    End With

    For i = 2 To 2187
        Set rgMatch = rgSearch.Find(wsSheet.Cells(i, y)) ' y = 1 or 11 (opposite of above!)
        blMatch = False

        If Not rgMatch Is Nothing Then
            stAddress = rgMatch.Address             

            Do Until rgMatch Is Nothing Or rgMatch.Address = stAddress
                If rgMatch.Offset(0, y).Value = Cells(i, 12).Value Then
                    Cells(i, 20) = Cells(i, 1).Value
                    Cells(i, 21) = Cells(i, 11).Value
                    Cells(i, 22) = Cells(i, 4).Value
                    Cells(i, 23) = Cells(i, 16).Value
                    blMatch = True
                Else

                End If

                Set rgMatch = rgSearch.FindNext(rgMatch)
            Loop


        End If
        If Not blMatch Then
            Cells(i, 24) = "No match"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I've made a lot of assumptions in there and there's a few variables you'll have to replace. You could also probably use application.worksheetfunction.match but .find is quicker and more awesome

Comment: Thank you for your input that is very helpful! Does this code do what I am asking it to do though? I need a pair of cells to be compared to another pair of cells iterated through two different columns, I don't want to compare one pair of cells to just another pair in another column I would like to compare one pair of cells to every cell in the other column and then return the matches.

Comment: ok i guess that was just my initial observation... hoping that would magically fix everything without me having to think more :) 

Your code doesn't match your question: you say you're going through row by row and trying to find a match in a column, but your code is only looking for matches in the same row... (that is, "i" is the same for every condition)

I'll update my answer with a suggestion

Comment: Wow, that looks impressive and intimidating! LOL, I tried applying this code and it runs a run time error '424' and says object required in the middle of the with statement after i plugged in (1,1) and (2187,1) for the range.

Comment: wsSheet will need to be something valid... either set it to a worksheet, or just use the actual worksheet object directly... i.e. by default, excel creates sheets "Sheet 1" "sheet 2" etc... i.e. the text name in the tab says "Sheet 1" etc... but they're also accessible directly as object, conveniently named sheet1, sheet2, sheet3 etc (i.e. without the space) so both these things are valid: thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet 1").activate and sheet1.activate...

you can rename that codename in the "properties" in VBA... change it to wsSheet for example... or set wsSheet = thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet 1")